# Using outside function in dplyr to standardize values via selected geometric mean. (Getting it via sample instead of geom mean of full column)

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics

Good evening fellow programmers/statistians etc.

I'm trying to standardize a set of variables dividing them by the geometric mean of a set of (same or not) variables I'm using as reference. Problem is, when trying to get it to work via dplyr, I'm getting results that I suspect are not the ones they should be if I do it case by case.

I have here some code explaining what I have done and why it failed. But It seems that dplyr is not getting my values via sample/row-wise, and instead is taking the full column to do my geometric mean.

I have been reviewing some questions, including some about geometric means, but for now I have not yet found how to solve it.

```
# A set of functions I'm using to calculate the geom mean.
gm_mean = function(x, na.rm=TRUE){
  exp(sum(log(x[x > 0]), na.rm=na.rm) / length(x))
}
gm_mean2 = function(x, na.rm=TRUE){
  exp(mean(log(x[x > 0]), na.rm=TRUE))
}
# And also psych::geometric.mean()

# x <- c(4, 8, 9, 9, 12, 14, 17)
# gm_mean(x)  # It works as intended.
# gm_mean2(x)  #It works as intended.
# psych::geometric.mean(x) #Indeed it works
```

So, using the iris dataset, I want to standardize a set of columns (coln1), dividing by the geometric mean of another set of columns (Which I would want to set as a variable, but since I'm not getting it to work as separate, I'm trying them without grouping them in a variable)

For now I have tried this (and failed)

```
library(dplyr)
coln1 <- colnames(iris)[1:2]
coln1 <- colnames(iris)[1:2]
iris %>% mutate(across( any_of(coln1),  ~ .x / psych::geometric.mean(c(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)) )) ## Doesn't work as intended? No. Not at all.

# Let me illustrate. Value that we are getting doing it case by case its == to the output?
iris[1,1] / psych::geometric.mean(c(iris[1,1],iris[1,2]))
1.207 != 1.2187
iris[1,1] / psych::geometric.mean(c(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Sepal.Width))
1.2817 == 1.287
# Its doing it by taking the full column of values, all of them, and not the values corresponding to that sample (in this case 2, but we could have more or less variables changing it in the psych:geometri.c.mean.)


# Notes.
# The geometric mean is the nth root of n products or e to the mean log of x. Useful for describing non-normal, i.e., geometric distributions. We are usign it via psych:: because it could be negative and we should solve that.

# iris %>% mutate(across( any_of(coln1),  ~ .x / exp(mean(log(Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width)))   )) # No. Cause this is not using the mean since its one value instead of two.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've done a great job setting it up, it's just 'rowwise()' that you're missing really! I've re-arranged the logic in the mutate call but it's basically just rowwise.

```
coln1 <- colnames(iris)[3:4]

iris %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(geo.mean = psych::geometric.mean(c(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)),
         across(.cols = all_of(coln1), .fns = ~ .x / geo.mean, .names = '{.col}_{.fn}'))
    
# A tibble: 150 x 8
# Rowwise: 
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species geo.mean Petal.Length_1 Petal.Width_1
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>      <dbl>          <dbl>         <dbl>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa      4.22          0.331        0.0473

# prove it's correctly functioning with first entry:
1.4 / psych::geometric.mean(c(5.1, 3.5))
[1] 0.3313667

0.2 / psych::geometric.mean(c(5.1, 3.5))
[1] 0.04733811
```

Comment: Thank you! And thank your for your kind words too! Didnt know about the rowwise in dplyr. I was atm creating an ID variable and doing an "group by" and ungroup before and after the mutate. Just an aditional question regarding your marvelous and direct answer, If i wanted just to substitute the values to get a new already standarize dataframe, should I just drop the .names in order to them to be the same as the original data and thus they substitute them, right? (although maybe im keeping these and change the .fn to "standarized" or something.

Comment: No problem :) Yes you're correct if you drop the '.names' argument it will simply overwrite the original data column (although columns are free so why not keep em all aha). And yes if you change the .names argument to '{.col}_standardized' that would also work nicely.

Comment: Thank you again @Bowhaven. Btw I just opened a question about using a string vector of the names of the variables to use it on the geometric mean part instead of writting them in symbol. Do you by any chance know how could I pass it as a vector of variables there? Because I got in my real dataset only like 5 but im doing this repeatedly across multiple variations of those five and it gets really code messy.

Comment: Yes, all sorted using 'c_across'! Check out my answer and don't forget to vote :)